# Can IContainer persist across methods in unit test?

Tags: autofac

In my unit test, I also make use of Autofac a lot ( reasons: it's simpler to resolve components that way, plus I get to test my Autofac registrations-- yes, they can be buggy, and it resembles my real life application usage).

This is how I do it typically:

```
[Test]
[Timeout(/* some timeout */)]
public void RunTest()
{
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // Registration
            builder.RegisterType<ConsoleOutput>().As<IOutput>();

            // Build the container.
            var container = builder.Build();


            // Resolve an instance of the IOutput interface from the container.
            var output = container.Resolve<IOutput>();


            //use the output
            
}
```

Take note that I don't wrap the container in an `using` block in any of my test, and for every single test I create a new `ContainerBuilder` and `IContainer`.

But I can't help to notice that if I run all these tests at one go, some of them will take exceedingly a long time, and trigger the Timeout attribute, which makes the tests fail. If I rerun those failed ( selected) tests, then they complete in a short time and no failure.

I have no idea why this is happening. But **could it be that if I don't dispose IContainer properly, there will be leftovers and whatever they are, they will impact the subsequent test runs?**

Comment: Why don't you show two actual tests that fail along with all relevant code (in other words, provide a [mre])? Guessing that an IoC container randomly freezes up is unproductive.

Comment: @CodeCaster, the whole thing involves just too many dependencies, and too many code, and the failure is just... timeout, there is no concrete exception message.

Comment: So what answers are you looking for? "Don't use a container in unit tests"? Or "use the `PleaseNoTimeOut = true` property"?